Boy draws and gets in trouble?
I don't remember much of this movie (Curse my horrible memory) But from what I do remember, this kid (one parent may be dead) has this sketchbook full of these depressing and creepy drawings that he does. They might be a comic, not sure. Anyhow, the teacher or another adult finds the drawings and the parent(s?) are called. Kid gets in trouble. The kid is around 13-16 and has darker hair. Can't remember the kid's face ,but it was in color and was kinda sad. I think at least one character died. What's  this movie? I watched to movie as a VHS or on TV. I might've seen it around 2007-2014. 

Might be WE BOUGHT A ZOO
A recent widow, Matt Damon, is called to the school over some disturbing drawings his son has drawn.  The father decides to embark on a new adventure and buys a zoo.

Thanks! This was the movie, now I need to watch it again.

You should add some more juice to your answer, at least put a link to the Wikipedia or IMDb entry to the movie.

And @LuckyTiamat, if this is the correct answer, don't forget to approve it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

@LuckyTiamat, I was going to say it was a toss-up between We Bought a Zoo and The Sixth Sense, as both films contain that element. But yes, I'm glad you found the correct answer!
